# filter Object of arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this Object of arrays:

`foo = {morning: [1,2,3,4,5], afternoon: [1,2,3,4,7]}`

I want to write a function that returns this object but remove a particular value.

ex: I want to remove the number `3` in afternoon. 
The function would return `{morning: [1,2,3,4,5], afternoon: [1,2,4,7]}`

```
myFunction = (partsOfDay, number) => {
  // do something
 // returns the object of arrays but without the specified value
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help :) although none of the duplicates mentioned are actual duplicates of my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without changing the source object using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

The properties of the returned object will still point to the source object but the filtered array properties will be copied with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const foo = { morning: [1,2,3,4,5], afternoon: [1,2,3,4,7] };

const myFilter = (obj, prop, value) => Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc[key] = key === prop && Array.isArray(val) ? val.filter(x => x !== value) : val;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(myFilter(foo, 'afternoon', 3));
console.log(myFilter(foo, 'morning', 3));
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: This did the trick ! thank you very much @jo_va :) Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, something like this

```
var partsOfDay = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

myFunction = (partsOfDay, number) => {
  var filtered = partsOfDay.filter(function(value, index, arr){
    return value != number;
  });
}
```

Refer for more [here](https://love2dev.com/blog/javascript-remove-from-array/)

Comment: Where's the object (`foo` in the question) in your answer?

Comment: HI @MyTwoCents, thank you for your help, but the difficulty here is that it is an object of arrays, not just an array; and I need the function to return the whole object, but without the unwanted value. If I simply loop through both arrays to remove the `3` in `"morning"`, it will remove the `3` in both `"morning"` and `"afternoon"`.